# como podria hacer un filtro al estilo de mercadolibre en angular?

Tags: angular, url, filtro

Se que un filtro al estilo de páginas como `mercadolibre.com` básicamente son peticiones a una API, que te devuelve resultados y los muestras en el Front. Pero lo que no encuentro como hacer es la parte de las URL que se van modificando a medida que vas aplicando filtros. Para que se entienda mejor mi pregunta voy a ilustrarla con un ejemplo:

cuándo se entra al home de mercadolibre, la URL se ve así:

[image: home]

si escribo por ejemplo, playstation 5 en el buscador, ahora la URL cambia a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si ahora filtro por artículos usados, entonces ahora la URL cambia a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A eso me refiero exactamente, como podría implementar eso en angular? tiene que ver con las rutas? estoy comenzando en Angular y esto actualmente es un desafío para mi. De la forma en que yo iba a hacer era tener una ruta para filtro, digamos: `localhost//localhost:4200/filtro` y desde aquí simplemente hacer peticiones al api con los paramtros que el usuario vaya seleccionando, podría ser una peticion de tipo post con los parametros en el cuerpo de la petición, pero la URL siempre sería la misma `localhost//localhost:4200/filtro` nunca se modificaría, y creo que eso no estaría bien por que veo que todas las páginas lo hacen igual, la URL se va modificando a medida que vas filtrando los datos.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme con esta duda, no es una pregunta basada en opiniones, quiero saber de que forma se logra esto en Angular.

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar,

Saludos!

Comment: simplemente pasas por parametros los datos de las busquedas para usarlas, `http://localhost:4200/filtro/:products/:quantity` y asi le puedes seguir agregando mas parametros

Comment: Es decir, son simples peticiones get pasando los parámetros en la query ?

Comment: son simples rutas recibiendo parametros, dentro de esas rutas puedes obtener los aprametros ingresados y de esa forma pides los datos a la bbdd para mostrarlos

Comment: en la configuracion de tu ruta hace algo como esto `{ path: 'filtro/:parametro', component: ParametroComponent }` luego desde el router traes el modulo params `import { Params } from '@angular/router'` y lo utilizas para extraer los parametros pasados a cierta ruta

Comment: Bien... y debo definir una ruta para cada una, es decir, cuando filtro por un solo parametros la ruta sería del estilo filtro/:parametro, si son 2 parametros entonces debo crear otra ruta para 2 parametros, si son 3 parametros entonces otra ruta para 3 parametros y así sucesivamente ? xq creo haber leído que esa era la forma.

Comment: exacto, pero trata de que el primer parámetro sea fijo, es decir, para mostrar todos los productos por id usa: `http://localhost:4200/products/:id` si vas a mostrar otra cosa por ejemplo algunos usuarios `http://localhost:4200/usuarios/:id` cambia solamente el primer parámetro, luego si necesitas mas datos para traer un usuario en especifico debes crear otra ruta `http://localhost:4200/usuairio/:id/:nombre` y así

Comment: Tienes que ir encadenando con rutas hijas para llegar a esos filtros que deseas.

Comment: @AlexisNarvaez como sería mas o menos? estoy todavía con esto y no he podido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías definir múltiples rutas para manejar los parámetros de búsqueda.

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // ...
  {
    path: 'busqueda/:termino,
    component: 'BusquedaComponent'
  },
  {
    path: 'busqueda/:categoria/:termino,
    component: 'BusquedaComponent'
  },
  {
    path: 'busqueda/:categoria/:estado/:termino,
    component: 'BusquedaComponent'
  }
  // ...
]
```

Y recibir estos parámetros en tu componente con `ActivatedRoute`

busqueda.component.ts

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
// ...

constructor (private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

public getParams(){
  let categoria = this.route.snapshot.paraMap.get('categoria');
  let termino = this.route.snapshot.paraMap.get('termino');
  // ...
}
```

---

O puedes hacerlo con [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). En este caso, defines una única ruta ya que los parámetros no la modifican a pesar de que aún siguen estando visible en la URL. Solo que de este modo, tu URL no se verá como

```
https://mitienda.com/busqueda/consolas/usado/ps5
```

Sino así

```
https://mitienda.com/busqueda?categoria=consolas&estado=usado&termino=ps5
```

Entonces, tu ruta será

```
{
  path: 'busqueda',
  component: 'BusquedaComponent'
}
```

Puedes navegar con estos parámetros de esta forma:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
// ...
    
constructor (private router: Router) {}

// ...
this.router.navigate(['busqueda'], { queryParams: { categoria: 'consolas', termino: 'ps5' } })
// ...
```

Y acceder a ellos así:

```
let categoria = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('categoria');
```

---

Puedes investigar un poco más en este enlace: [Angular Router](https://angular.io/guide/router),

Comment: Crees q no estaría mal hacerlo con query string? veo que usando esa opción, solo tendría mi componente filtro, entonces iría agregando cada filtro (por ejemplo: usado) a la query y enviaría eso al backend y luego en el bakend me encargaría de obtener los parametros y hacer las consultas correspondientes en la base de datos para devolver los resultados. el filtro que tengo es como el de mercado libre, si hago click en "usado" entonces automaticamente se debería de disparar la peticion ara obtener ese resultado, si luego selecciono una marca, entonces hace otra peticion, sería /usado&nombreMarca

Comment: Sí, funcionaría bastante bien y ciertamente es muy común ver que tiendas y plataformas manejan todo esto con Query Strings. También puedes *observar* cuando se hagan cambios en los queryParams y así ejecutar automáticamente tu consulta al back. `this.router.queryParams.subscribe(params => {  /* tu lógica acá */  })`

Comment: vale, aún no he comenzado a aplicar esta lógica, pero creo estar un poco mas claro, espero no estancarme. muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Amigo tendrás tiempo para una consulta respecto al mismo tema? si no es mucha molestia, claro.

Comment: Reviso la plataforma cada tanto. Solo deja tu pregunta que igual me llega la notificación y te respondo apenas la lea. ;)

Comment: Gracias! bueno... el tema es que comencé a implementar el filtro, tengo algunos select (los cuales en realidad son una lista), a medida que voy seleccionando uno de ellos debería hacer la petición al back y mostrar los resultados correspondientes. Pero veo que es bastante trabajo y no se si es que estoy haciendo algo mal o es normal, por ejemplo... veo que tengo que agregar el filtro que representa cada select a la URL, y enviar esto al back, pero tambien pienso, si el usuario copia esa URL y la pega en otra parte, debería poder marcar esos select que aparecen en la URL para poder mostrar los

Comment: resultados correspondientes, entonces tendría que cada vez que cargue el componente, evaluar la URL, extraerlos y de alguna manera setear los select (marcarlos), no se si me explico. Entonces, veo que es bastante trabajo, y no se si sería la forma correcta o me estoy complicando mucho? quisiera la opinión de alguien como tu que al parecer ya lo has trabajado, esta es la primera vez que me toca hacer algo con cierta complejidad-

Comment: Sí, yo haría eso. Si usas el `subscribe` de mi comentario anterior, podrías poner la lógica allí para que se actualice cada vez que cambien los parámetros (y también cuando se cargue abra tu página con una URL ya compuesta). Puede que sea tedioso, aunqeu si tienes tus filtros en arrays puede que sea más sencillo si lo recorres y que los parámetros coincidan con los handlers de tus filtros.

Comment: Y por ejemplo si puedo filtrar por varias categorias a la vez, estuve intentando agregar un array al queryParams, pero no pude, entonces lo estoy agregando asi: categoria=dietas&categoria=sinLactosa , es decir se repite la categoria, habria una forma de mejorar eso ?

Comment: Si quieres que la URL esté más limpia, yo probaría a separar por coma (o algún otro caracter), y luego hacer, por ejemplo, para `categoria=dietas,sinLactosa`, sería algo como `let categoriasSeleccionadas:string[] = params['categoria'].split(',')`. Lo que vendría siendo como `categoriasSeleccionadas = ['dietas', 'sinLactosa']`... Espero te sirva. Disculpa la demora.